# Angular: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in dev mode, yet bindings update in production mode

Tags: angular, binding, angular-changedetection

The following simple Angular app, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i9uhfz?file=src%2Fmain.ts, understandably yields `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in dev mode. However, even after enbaling prod mode, i.e. running without the added change detection cycle, the value in the parent component updates as the child component changes the value. Why is that?